# Get elements inside a div VBA

Tags: html, vba

I have the HTML below:

```
 <div id="div_2_1_3" class="Button  CoachView CoachView_show" 
   data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_5b0cf92e_d5be_41c3_b0d3_f101b717826c.Button"
  data-binding="" data-bindingtype="" data-config="config3" 
   data-viewid="Button3" data-eventid="boundaryEvent_4">

      <button type="button" class="BPMButton BPMButtonBorder"
```

and I have to click in button that class is BPMButton BPMButtonBorder.

I am trying this code, but is returning the error: Run-time error: '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.
How can I click on BPMButton BPMButtonBorder?

```
sub html

Set divs = ie.getElementBytagname("div")
For Each divi In divs   
    If divi.id = "div_2_1_3" Then Set botoes = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")
       For Each bt In botoes
            If bt.ClassName = "BPMButton BPMButtonBorder" Then
                bt.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next bt
Next divi
end sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub html
    Dim div, botoes, bt

    'edit - added missing .document
    Set div = ie.document.getElementById("div_2_1_3")
    Set botoes = div.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON")

    For Each bt In botoes
       Debug.Print bt.ClassName
       If bt.ClassName = "BPMButton BPMButtonBorder" Then
           bt.Click
           Exit For
       End If
    Next bt

end sub
```

Comment: Tks for your edits and answer, but I am getting into the same error. Now at line **Set div = ie.getElementById("div_2_1_3")**

Answer (score 0):

Tim, I believe that was missing **document** after **ie.**.
It works with this code:

```
Set botoes = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    For Each bt In botoes
Debug.Print bt.innertext
    If bt.innertext = "Run Now" Then
       bt.Click
   Exit For
End If
Next bt
```